# Problem with tableview cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am using these following codes to display multiple images on a table view. One row need to display 4 only images

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger) section {

    //Resize auto complete table based on how many elements will be displayed in the table
    return (int)ceil([wordsInSentence count]/4.0);
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"entered forRowAtIndexPath");
    if ((indexPath.row % 2) == 0) {

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    }
    else {

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }

}
```

On the button click wich will display table view I wrote the below code

```
-(IBAction)setImageOnTableView
{
    NSLog(@"entered setImageOnTableView");
    j=1;

    tableView.hidden=NO;

    //Breaking the sentence into words and then placing it in an array
    wordsInSentence=[[youSaid.text uppercaseString] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    [wordsInSentence retain];
    [youSaid resignFirstResponder];

    [tableView reloadData];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    NSLog(@"entered cellForRowAtIndexPath");
    //j=1;
    static NSString *AutoCompleteRowIdentifier = @"AutoCompleteRowIdentifier";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier] autorelease];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:nil];

        for (int i=0; i <= [wordsInSentence count]; ++i) {
            UIImageView *imageView1 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30+90*(i%4), 20, 70, 100)] autorelease] ;
            imageView1.tag = i+1;
            [imageViewArray insertObject:imageView1 atIndex:i];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView1];
            //[imageView1 release];
          }    
    }

    int photosInRow;
    if ( (indexPath.row < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1) || ([wordsInSentence count] % 4 == 0) ) {
        photosInRow = 4;
    } else {
        photosInRow = [wordsInSentence count] % 4;
    }

    for ( int i = 1; i <=photosInRow ; i++ ){            
        imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:j];
        [self **showImage**:imageView];

    }
    return cell;
}


//method used to show the images on the table view by checking the category 
//and images in the category
-(void)**showImage**:(UIImageView *)imageView
{
    NSLog(@"entered showImage");

//this method will check if more than 1 image is present in the category    
    if([self searchImagesInSameCategory:[wordsInSentence objectAtIndex:j-1]]>1)
    {
        UIButton *descriptiveButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [descriptiveButton setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, 30, 30)];
        [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];

        [descriptiveButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showPopOver1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        descriptiveButton.tag=j;
        [imageView addSubview:descriptiveButton];
        globalString=[wordsInSentence objectAtIndex:j-1];
    }
}
```

In this code when I displayed 4 images it will display 4. If I displayed 3 images after displaying 4 images, 3 images are displaying but still 4 th image is presenting in table view. How can I fix this. Please can any one help me...

The main problem is, an image view that displayed before is not removing from the cell.

Comment: any brilliant guys from Stack overflow...

Comment: what is [cell.contentView addSubview:nil]; supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table cells can be (and in your code, are) cached and reused - which means that for every call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath::` you should make sure that the cell you are returning is correct (has the correct images). In your case, I would simply clear the cell of all subviews/image views and recreate them for every fetch.